# Does LUKS decrypt the whole hard disk at the time of boot?

Tags: encryption, luks

When I boot the system after providing my decryption password, does LUKS decrypt the whole hard drive ? Or just use a file system driver to lazily decrypt the data on demand and as it is accessed ?

Answer (score 0):

Decryption of the whole hard drive would require reading the whole hard drive.

The [dm-crypt wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) states that `dm-crypt` is a device mapper target, hence a block device.
Since the real file system (`ext4`, `btrfs`, ...) lay on top of that and is not even aware of the underlying block device, it has no reason to read (and decrypt) unneeded blocks.

Comment: Could you include the links for some documentation to support your answer